# how to add a string to a string array with comma

Tags: java, jsp

I have created a web application, in which the user input data in JSP table and then store data in database when user clicks on Save.

In this application, I have concated all the columns data in one row and stored in array which is posted to INSERT page to insert data into DataBase. There I split all the elements in array with the ","(comma).
 
The problem I got here is, when user enters a string with comma in one single column then at theme time of splitting this array, the array size increases to actual size and getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly like as:

```
Collections.addAll(arrayList, input.split(","));
```

like as simple example:

```
String returnedItems = "a,b,c";
List<String> sellItems = Arrays.asList(returnedItems.split(","));
```

Now iterate over the list and append each item to a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String item: sellItems){
    if(sb.length() > 0){
        sb.append(',');
    }
    sb.append(item);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29**

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29**

Answer (score 0):

To each value enterned by user add seperator like $ or ; or :
Then you add this values to the array:
value1$value2$something$value3$

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> bla = new ArrayList<String>();
        bla.add("1$");
        bla.add("2,3$");//2,3 is an one value
        bla.add("4$"); 
        ArrayList<String> newOne = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bla.size(); i++) {

        String[] array = bla.get(i).split("$");
        newOne.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array)));
        String fixed = newOne.get(i).substring(0, newOne.get(i).length()-1);
        newOne.set(i, fixed);




        }

        System.out.println(newOne);
        System.out.println(newOne.size());
    }
```

Comment: When you output that you just get rid of seperator

Comment: Yes, I have added a seperator @|@, Which is like **Value1**@|@**Value2**@|@**Value3**. My problem is that when user adds comma in **Value1** like **Val,ue1**, then the **Value1** is also splitting into two elements like **Val** and **ue1**

Comment: or you can change it and add fixed as a whole thing just take out newOne.set... outside of the loop and instead of set use add